# Wrong UV island stacking

Tags: uv

I have some similar model parts, so I decided to stack them. In the first photo everything is right – one island is laying perfectly under second.

[image]

But in photo 2 – some faces of first island are under second, and some faces are above.

[image]

Because of that, I got issues with baking (world space normal map in photo 3).
[image]

I used UVpackmaster (vertex position with correct vertices), also asked friend to stack it with Rizom, but problem stays.

Any ideas what can cause this?